# A DCG that matches the rest of the input

Tags: prolog, dcg

This is the predicate that does what it should, namely, collect whatever is left on input when part of a DCG:

```
rest([H|T], [H|T], []).
rest([], [], []).
```

but I am struggling to define this as a DCG... Or is it at all doable?

This of course is not the same (although it does the same when used in the same manner):

```
rest([H|T]) --> [H], !, rest(T).
rest([]) --> [].
```

The reason I *think* I need this is that the `rest//1` is part of a set of DCG rules that I need to parse the input. I could do `phrase(foo(T), Input, Rest)`, but then I would have to call another `phrase(bar(T1), Rest)`.

Say I know that all I have left on input is a string of digits that I want as an integer:

```
phrase(stuff_n(Stuff, N), `some other stuff, 1324`).

stuff_n(Stuff, N) -->
    stuff(Stuff),
    rest(Rest),
    {   number_codes(N, Rest),
        integer(N)
    }.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own silly question:

@CapelliC gave a solution that works (+1). It does something I don't understand :-(, but the real issue was that I did not understand the problem I was trying to solve. The real problem was:

### Problem

You have as input a code list that you need to parse. The result should be a term. You know quite close to the beginning of this list of codes what the rest looks like. In other words, it begins with a "keyword" that defines the contents. In some cases, after some point in the input, the rest of the contents do not need to be parsed: instead, they are collected in the resulting term as a code list.

### Solution

One possible solution is to break up the parsing in two calls to `phrase/3` (because there is no reason not to?):

1. Read the keyword (first call to `phrase/3`) and make it an atom;
2. Look up in a table what the rest is supposed to look like;
3. Parse **only what needs to be parsed** (second call to `phrase/3`).

### Code

So, using an approach from (O'Keefe 1990) and taking advantage of `library(dcg/basics)` available in SWI-Prolog, with a file `rest.pl`:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

codes_term(Codes, Term) :-
    phrase(dcg_basics:nonblanks(Word), Codes, Codes_rest),
    atom_codes(Keyword, Word),
    kw(Keyword, Content, Rest, Term),
    phrase(items(Content), Codes_rest, Rest).

kw(foo, [space, integer(N), space, integer(M)], [], foo(N, M)).
kw(bar, [], Text, bar(Text)).
kw(baz, [space, integer(N), space], Rest, baz(N, Rest)).

items([I|Is]) -->
    item(I),
    items(Is).
items([]) --> [].

item(space) --> " ".
item(integer(N)) --> dcg_basics:integer(N).
```

It is important that here, **the "rest" does not need to be handled by a DCG rule** at all.

### Example use

This solution is nice because it is deterministic, and very easy to expand: just add clauses to the `kw/4` table and `item//1` rules. (Note the use of the `--traditional` flag when starting SWI-Prolog, for double-quote delimited code lists)

```
$ swipl --traditional --quiet
?- [rest].
true.

?- codes_term("foo 22 7", T).
T = foo(22, 7).

?- codes_term("bar 22 7", T).
T = bar([32, 50, 50, 32, 55]).

?- codes_term("baz 22 7", T).
T = baz(22, [55]).
```

Comment: One note: the backquote-notation is SWI specific. Standard notation uses double-quotes.

Comment: This remark is specific to SWI7. With `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,codes).` also SWI 7 behaves as expected.

Comment: You are close to the 10-edits limit which will transform your answer into a community-wiki-answer.

Comment: You will lose ownership of an answer after about 10 edits. So further upvotes will not improve your rep

Comment: @false Aha :) well increasing my rep was not why I answered my own question anyway. I was just embarrassed by the silliness of the question.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (that doesn't leave a choice point behind) is to use the `call//1` built-in non-terminal with a lambda expression. Using Logtalk's lambda expression syntax to illustrate:

```
rest(Rest) --> call({Rest}/[Rest,_]>>true).
```

This solution is a bit nasty, however, as it uses a variable with a dual role in the lambda expression (which triggers a warning with the Logtalk compiler). An usage example:

```
:- object(rest).

    :- public(test/2).
    test(Input, Rest) :-
        phrase(input(Rest), Input).

    input(Rest) --> [a,b,c], rest(Rest).

    rest(Rest) --> call({Rest}/[Rest,_]>>true).
%   rest([C|Cs]) --> [C|Cs].    % Carlo's solution

:- end_object.
```

Assuming the above object is saved in a `dcg_rest.lgt` source file:

```
$ swilgt
...

?- {dcg_rest}.
*     Variable A have dual role in lambda expression: {A}/[A,B]>>true
*       in file /Users/pmoura/Desktop/dcg_rest.lgt between lines 13-14
*       while compiling object rest
% [ /Users/pmoura/Desktop/dcg_rest.lgt loaded ]
% 1 compilation warning
true.

?- rest::test([a,b,c,d,e], Rest).
Rest = [d, e].
```

You should be able to get the same results using other lambda expressions implementation such as Ulrich's `lambda` library.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you suggest this solution because it does not leave behind a choice point? I try to avoid warnings almost religiously.... I still don't know whether the very first, non-DCG definition of `rest/3` in my question (which can still be used by `phrase`) is not better than any "hacked" DCG rule.

Comment: The warning is there because usually using a variable as both a lambda free variable and a lambda parameter is a programmer typo or error. Not in this case, however. But I do think that a non-DCG definition of rest/3 is not an elegant solution as it breaks the abstraction provided by DCGs and also assumes a specific translation from grammar rules to predicate clauses.

Comment: "... and also assumes a specific translation from grammar rules to predicate clauses": This is exactly why I felt the need to ask. Thank you for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 0):

could be

```
rest([C|Cs]) --> [C|Cs] .
```

at least in SWI-Prolog, it seems to run (I used library(dcg/basics) to get the number)

```
line(I,R) --> integer(I), rest(R).
?- phrase(line(N,R), `6546 okok`).
N = 6546,
R = [32, 111, 107, 111, 107]
```

Comment: It leaves a choice point behind, not sure why. Do you know what `'$append'/3` does? (look at the expanded version). I actually had this along the way but I couldn't understand how it works...

Comment: $append/3 it's identical to append/3 - same plain old Prolog definition. It's defined in init.pl, while append/3 is in lists.pl. I think it could be required to avoid dependencies on lists library while expanding DCGs.

Comment: About the choicepoint: a cut should do, and could also make sense to have it, otherwise rest//1 is easily inlined

Comment: What do you mean by "easily inlined"? And where would you put the cut? Right after `rest//1` in the definition of `line//2`, or after `line//2` wherever it is used? And yes, it would be nice to have it deterministic, since this is the intended semantics of `rest//2`?

Comment: rest([C|Cs]) --> [C|Cs], !. Inlined I mean that instead of `...,rest(R), ...` we can write `...,[C|Cs],{R=[C|Cs]}....` (untested, was my understanding...)

Comment: The cut at the end of `rest//1` does break it, somehow. It also changes what it expands to. The inlined version you propose is identical in behavior to having it as a separate DCG rule (including the effect of the cut). The cut probably needs to be after the call to `phrase/2`?

Comment: you're right, `rest//1` is probably playing in the grey area of term_expansion complexities. Of course, this problem could be the true inspiration behind O'Keefe code you cited in your own answer (I don't see your solution as clear as I would like). About $append/3, seems that it get completely blown away from term_expansion, what I mean, `trace` doesn't show the code we see with `listing`

Comment: The solution is my answer is not clear, and it took me a few attempts to get it to the point where it fits my problem. But my "solution" is not to parse the "rest" at all! :-) I guess the underlying issue is the impedance mismatch between "parsing" a list (of atoms) and trying to convert input from the outside into Prolog terms (especially when the input is from a stream and `phrase_from_file` does not work).

Comment: This answer uses two features incompatible with ISO systems like SICStus: Writing [X|Xs] in the rule-body is an error, using back-quotes instead of double-quotes (`set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes)` fixes that)